# RequireJS - Return after onready

Tags: javascript, requirejs, jaydata

I have a RequireJS module and I want to only return an object after it's onReady() event has been called.

```
define([
'kendovendor', 
'TodoDB',
'jaydatakendo'
], function (kendo,tododb,jdvend) {


    var onlinedb = new Avcheck.Layered.Model.AvCheckContext({
        name: 'oData',
        oDataServiceHost: '/WcfDataServiceTest.svc'
    });

    var offlinedb = new Avcheck.Layered.Model.AvCheckContext({
        name: 'webSql',
        databaseName: 'TodoDB'
    });

var fullDB;
    offlinedb.onReady(function () { 
         fullDB = onlinedb.AChecklistComplete.include('AChecklistTop').include('Aircraft').include('Aircraft.Vendor').asKendoDataSource();

//calling this inside onReady() returns nothing as there is a timing issue
 return {
        onlinedb: onlinedb,
        offlinedb: offlinedb,
        FullDB: fullDB
    };


    });



});
```

The reason for this is that the JayData include() will only work after the database is ready. But another module is using this module as a requirement, and this module returns nothing. If I call return outside of onReady(), then it returns a valid object, but FullDB is not set properly.

How can I set up RequireJS to work nicely with an objects onready() event? Thanks.